# Returning a div component after onClick event in React and Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am working on a to-do list with React and TypeScript. I have a "done" button in the DOM for showing my completed tasks after I have checked them. I am trying to see if I can return anything at the moment before adding more information. Here is what I have so far, I have tried to add a useState hook to the function (see below):

```
const ShowDone = () => {
  const [showTasks, setShowTasks] = useState(false)
  const onClick = () => setShowTasks(true)
  return (
    <div>
      <button className="doneButton" onClick={onClick}>Done</button>
      { showTasks ? <Tasks /> : null }
    </div>
  )
}

const Tasks = () => (
  <div id="results" className="task-results">
    Some Results
  </div>

);
```

the above looked OK to me but when I click the done button in dev tools, nothing happens and I get the following error message, stating that it is an invalid hook call:

```
      throw new Error('Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for' + ' one of the following reasons:\n' + '1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)\n' + '2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks\n' + '3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app\n' + 'See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.');
    }
```

I erased everything and just added console.log('hello') into the ShowDone function and that was fine, nothing wrong with the button itself. Not sure why this is occurring, did I put this function on the wrong line number in my App.tsx file? What about the invalid hooks error? What about my code makes this invalid?

Edit: I have added more of my code below, this is what is below the ShowDone function above.

```
const initialTodosString = localStorage.getItem("toDoList");

const initialTodos = initialTodosString
  ? JSON.parse(initialTodosString)
  : [myToDo1, myToDo2];

function App(): JSX.Element {
  const [toDos, setToDos] = useState<ToDo[]>(initialTodos);
  const [addingToDo, setAddingToDo] = useState(false);

  useEffect(
    function () {
      localStorage.setItem("toDoList", JSON.stringify(toDos));
    },
    [toDos]
  );

  function newTask() {
    setAddingToDo(true);
  }

  function handleFormSubmit(event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = Object.fromEntries(
      new FormData(event.target as HTMLFormElement)
    );
    setToDos([
      ...toDos,
      {
        title: data.Title as string,
        priority: parseInt(data.Priority as string) as 2 | 1,
        description: data.Description as string,
        checked: false || true,
      },
    ]);
  }

  if (addingToDo) {
    return (
      <div className="form-container">
        <form onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
          <h1>To Do Form </h1>
          <p>
            <label>Title</label>
          </p>
          <p>
            <input name="Title" className="input-field" id="title" />
          </p>
          <p>
            <label>Due Date</label>
          </p>
          <p>
            <input name="Date" type="date" className="input-field" />
          </p>
          <p>
            <label>Priority</label>
          </p>
          <p>
            <select name="Priority" className="input-field">
              <option className="important" value="1">
                Important
              </option>
              <option selected value="2">
                Normal
              </option>

              {/* <option>Urgent</option> */}
            </select>
          </p>
          <p>
            <label>Description</label>
          </p>
          <p>
            <input name="Description" className="input-field" />
          </p>
          <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Add" className="submit" />
          </p>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="greeting-container">
        <div className="greeting">
          <Greeting />
        </div>
        <button className="task-button" onClick={newTask}>
          New Task
        </button>
        <div className="date-container">
          Today is {new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", { weekday: "long" })}
          <br />
          <div className="current-date">
            {new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {
              month: "long",
              day: "2-digit",
            })}
            , {new Date().getFullYear()}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="task-container">
        <div className="task-counter">
          {toDos.length} {toDos.length === 1 ? "Task" : "Tasks"}
        </div>
        <div className="status-container">
          <button className="activeButton">Active</button>
          <button className="doneButton" onClick={ShowDone}>Done</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr />
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding! For some reason I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: "I erased everything and just added console.log('hello') into the ShowDone function and that was fine, nothing wrong with the button itself." - there *is* no "done" button if you do this, since that's in the JSX returned by the `ShowDone` component. It's an odd component name though. It almost sounds like you're trying to call `ShowDone` as an event handler in another component - in which case this is all completely wrong and the invalid hook call error is understandable. You need to give us more context as to what you're actually doing.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful response. What do you suggest I name it? I am still working on improving my naming conventions. I have made edits and have added the rest of my code to my question.

Comment: I've offered no opinion on naming, I've asked for more details - which you've given, and which have confirmed my suspicions. Your `ShowDone` makes no sense whatsoever as an event handler, and I have no idea what you are actually trying to do. (Although there is a strong naming convention that in React all component functions should start with a capital, and others like event handlers should not. But naming conventions are not the main problem here!)

Comment: Gotcha, I will explain: what I am trying to do is return a div after clicking the done button. The div I am trying to return after clicking the button is hidden when the page is loaded. It will show after I click the done button.

Comment: thanks, that allows me to answer with what you should do, I think (about to post it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes no sense to have an event handler, like your `ShowDone`, return JSX - or indeed anything at all. Like all event handlers, this will just (possibly) perform some side effects - the browser will completely ignore any return value you specify. (In your actual code your event handler pretends to be a component and calls the `useState` hook, thus breaking the Rules of Hooks as your error message says - and returns some JSX output for the button itself which was already rendered by `App`, which doesn't make sense at all.)

So here's how to actually do what I think you were trying to do. (Not the complete `App` component but just explaining the bits you need to add to it.) You need the `showTasks` state, and the conditional rendering of the `Tasks` component based on it, inside `App` itself. I've also altered the name of your event handler to `showDone`, starting with lower case, as it's convention in React that only functions representing components should start with an uppercase later:

```
function App(): JSX.Element {
    const [showTasks, setShowTasks] = useState(false)

    // somewhere in your component include this:
    const showDone = () => setShowTasks(true);

    // the rest of the component exactly as you had it
    return (
         // JSX output as you had it before, including this button:
         <button className="doneButton" onClick={showDone}>Done</button>
        
         // and including this at the appropriate place in the markup:
         { showTasks ? <Tasks /> : null }
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! This got rid of my error, but nothing is appearing when clicking the button, I will keep trying to figure out what's going on here. I appreciate your time!

Comment: Also great call out, I totally forgot about the starting with an uppercase letter will return a component!

Comment: I added the { showTasks ? <Tasks /> : null } in the right place in my DOM and it is working! Thank you! I appreciate your thoughtful explanation. Means so much!